# Can a PoA Network be corrupted by one node only?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225

The text from that link states that a single node can corrupt the blocks and is limited to just a signing limit.

What is the solution to prevent a node corrupting even some data in a PoA network? I know VeChain is using PoA. They have a big venture so I assume this issue is resolved.

The issue to me is not limiting damage but eliminating damage.

Has anyone found a reference to a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I did get an answer here - 
https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225

Apparently the POA algorithm does allow limits to be placed by the approval process in the network.

> @zillerium not at all. PoA is more in the field of classical consensus
>   algorithms where you have a simple honest majority assumption.
>   Depending on the kind of network faults you'll also tolerate, you can
>   either tolerate <1/2 malicious or <1/3. In some situations you can
>   tolerate all but one node being malicious but just not be able to
>   finalize anything. It all depends on the algorithm you use and your
>   assumptions